# "Dangerous" Android permissions that don't need to be accepted by users

Tags: android, permissions

[Google states](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element.html) that permissions with `dangerous` as the value of `protectionLevel` have to be granted by the user on installation time.

One example for such a `dangerous` [permission](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml) is `android.permission.INTERNET`. But although apps have declared to use this permissions, it's treated like a `normal` permission, thus the user won't be asked about it. This is also mentioned on [How-To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/190863/androids-app-permissions-were-just-simplified-now-theyre-much-less-secure/).

- Where does Google itself explain this behaviour?
- Why is the `INTERNET` permission still `dangerous`, but treated like a `normal` one? (instead of changing it to normal in the mapping file)
- Where does that happen? Is there another mapping for "dangerous, but too important to worry users" permissions? Or is it hardcoded?
- Are there other `dangerous` permissions than `INTERNET` where this applies?

Comment: "Why is the INTERNET permission still dangerous, but treated like a normal one?" -- Google has decided not to bother users with the `INTERNET` permission at all, as so many apps were requesting it, and that users should assume apps have Internet access. Privacy advocates were not amused by this decision.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can understand why Google has decided to not ask users about this permission. But why haven't they changed the protectionLevel to normal?

Comment: You'd have to ask Google.

Comment: Just to update anyone who stumbles on this. Google no longer lists `INTERNET` as a dangerous permission. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous